# From second to datetime sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to convert second in datetime format.
Example : 1521028270 -> 2018-03-14 11:52:02.393

Can someone help me?

Comment: Hmm. It looks *close* to unix timestamp format but if we assume that, I get `2018-03-14 11:51:10` (and, of course, you'll never recover milliseconds from this). Do you have more than a single example for us to reason from?

Comment: Unless you're using a very weird epoch, that's probably not the correct result. `SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, 1521028270, '19700101')` (using the much more common Unix epoch of 1970-01-01) gives `2018-03-14 11:51:10.000`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i have 'dd' (example: 1521029785) which is a number that represents the second. I want to trasform that in a datetime.

Comment: Yes, but you gave *one* example in your question and even then appear to have given two values that *aren't* equivalent.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever theoretically you could just do a DATEADD for seconds with a negative amount of the seconds mentioned by OP and provide the expected time provided the OP to derive a starting Datetime that would work in the case that he has some weird nonstandard offset that varies by about 58 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Using the logic provided by @Jeroen Mostert:

```
declare @a datetime = '19700101',
        @s int = 1521028270

select  dateadd(s, @s, @a)
```

Answer (score 1):

'1970-01-01' is starting(reference point) date

```
DECLARE @dt int = 1521028270;

SELECT DATEADD(s, @dt, '1970-01-01')
```